# VueJS forceUpdate for v-for is not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I started learning VueJS this week and I was trying to build a note app but I got into some problem :

```html
<div id="app">
        <h2>NOTES : </h2>
        <ol>
            <notelist v-for="n in notes" v-bind:note="n" v-bind:key="n.id">
            </notelist>
        </ol>
        <hr>
        <input id='ntitle'>
        <input id='ntext'>
        <button v-on:click="addnewnote"> + Add</button>
    </div>
```

and

```
Vue.component('notelist', {
    props: ['note'],
    template: '<li> {{ note.title }} - {{ note.text }}</li>'
  });

x = [
    {id:1,title : "Code" , text : "i should code tonight"},
]

if(localStorage.getItem("notes") == null){
    localStorage.setItem("notes" , JSON.stringify(x));
}

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: function() {
        return{
            notes : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes")),
        };

    },
    methods : {
        addnewnote(){
            var nte =  document.getElementById("ntitle").value;
            var ntt = document.getElementById("ntext").value;
            var nid = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes")).length + 1;

            var sd = {id:nid , title : nte , text : ntt};

            var NI = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes")).concat(sd));

            localStorage.setItem("notes" ,  NI);

           this.$forceUpdate()

        },



    }
  });
```

basically, I'm storing notes on localstorage and when the `+Add` is clicked a new note is added but the problem is that the list is not re-rendaring when a new item is added!
Here's my repl https://repl.it/@bauripalash/FrostyMemorableDecagons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to also update the `notes` component data property in method `addnewnote():

```
addnewnote() {
  const nte =  document.getElementById("ntitle").value;
  const ntt = document.getElementById("ntext").value;
  const nid = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes")).length + 1;

  const sd = { id: nid , title: nte , text: ntt };

  const NI = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes")).concat(sd);

  this.notes = NI;

  localStorage.setItem("notes" ,  JSON.stringify(NI));

  this.$forceUpdate()
}
```

This is so that the Vue component knows that a change has happened to data properties and can update accordingly. With this change you will not need forceUpdate(). Vue will not watch localStorage for changes and update notes component data property automatically, you need to do this manually.

Here is an [example](https://repl.it/repls/WorthwhileTransparentLearning) in action.

Also please consider avoiding use DOM methods to get property of inputs and instead actually use Vue v-model to bind the value of the input to a component data property.

```
<input v-model="ntitle" id="ntitle">
<input v-model="ntext" id="ntext">

// ...

data: function () {
  return {
    ntext: '',
    ntitle: '',
    notes: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes")),
  };
}

// ...

const sd = { id: nid, title: this.ntitle, text: this.ntext };
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thank you, I just had to make a little change , `this.notes = JSON.parse(NI);` as `NI` is previously JSON stringyfied.

Comment: Sure, I updated the answer to reflect that. You could consider saving and working with the parsed JSON in a variable instead of parsing and stringifying multiple times. Please mark the answer if it helped. Thanks!